# How can the Calinski-Harabasz index be used to select the number of clusters?

Tags: clustering

How can the Calinski-Harabasz index be used to select the number of clusters?

Answer (score 1):

The motivation of Calinski and Harabasz in the original paper is based on Analysis of Variance theory which involves sums of squared distances from the (cluster) means. This corresponds to k-means (and Ward's method) but not to any clustering method (such as k-medoids) that isn't based on the sum of squared distances to the cluster mean.

As far as I know (and I know a bit) there is no justification of the index for the latter methods.